# Generate radio with cakephp 1.3

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I need to generate Radio button with cake php format like this

```
<div class="radioset gender">
<div>
    <div>Male</div>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="1"/>
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <div>Female</div>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="0"/>
    </label>
</div>
```

I can not use

```
e($form->radio("User.sex",array(0=>"Male",1=>"Female"),array("legend"=>false)));
```

Because it can not generate HTML format that i want.
I use multi input like that

```
e($form->input( 'User.sex', array('type'=>'radio', 'options' => array(0=>""),'div'=>false, "error"=>false, 'label' => false ) ));
e($form->input( 'User.sex', array('type'=>'radio', 'options' => array(1=>""),'div'=>false, "error"=>false, 'label' => false ) ));
```

But when i submit form. Server can not get value.
Please help me how to do it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this format:

```
 echo $form->input('field', array(
'type' => 'radio',
'legend'=>'Group of Radio',
// 'after' => '--after--',
// 'between' => '--between---',
'separator' => '--separator--',
'default' => '--which is by default selected--',
  'options' => array('Button One', 'Button Two')
 ));
```

Comment: I can not use separator because i have difference value in separator.Example separator between <div></div> is A but another div is B.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with **Separator**. I.e

```
echo $this->Form->input('name', array( 'type' => 'radio',
                                     'before' => '<div>',
                                     'separator'=> '</div><div>',                                         
                                     'after' => '</div>',
                                     'options' =>  $option,
                                     'label' => true,
                                     "legend" => false
                                   )
                                );
```